# Reinstalling IIS on WinXP machine

Tags: iis, windows-xp

I am having problems making IIS on a Windows XP box server up ASP.NET pages.  I keep getting a general error that tells me to check the event log, but there is nothing in the event log.

After troubleshooting for several hours and being able to successfully server up the ASP.NET pages on several other WinXP machines, I have decided that I would like to reinstall IIS on the machine and see if that fixes the problem.

I went into Add/Remove Programs, Windows Components, and removed and then re-added IIS but it didn't seem to fix the issue.  Are there anymore methods for removing IIS and cleanly reinstalling a fresh install?  My only other option would be to reinstall WinXP on the machine, and I don't want to do that if I can avoid it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or quote of the err/exception details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Microsoft explanation on how to [fully remove IIS 5.1 from Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325889) and then reinstall it.

**To uninstall:**

1. Locate the Iis5.log file. Rename it to IIS5_old.log.
2. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.
3. At the command prompt, type net stop iisadmin /y.
4. Stop all services that depend on IIS services. To determine what services depend on IIS services, follow these steps:
5. In Task Manager, verify that Inetinfo.exe is not running. Also confirm that no processes that depend on IIS are running.
6. Click Start, click Run, type Appwiz.cpl, and then click OK.
7. In Control Panel, double-click Add/Remove Programs.
8. In the Add/Remove Programs window, click Add/Remove Windows Components.
9. In the Components box of the Windows Components Wizard, double-click Application Server.
10. Click to clear the Internet Information Services (IIS) check box, and then click OK.
11. In the Windows Components Wizard, click Next.
12. When the Windows Components Wizard completes the installation, click Finish.
13. Restart the computer.
14. Click Start, click Run, type Lusrmgr.msc, and then click OK.
15. In the Local Users and Groups windows, verify that the IWAM_computername and IUSR_computername account have been deleted.
16. Verify that the Inetsrv folder has been deleted. By default, the Inetsrv folder is located in the %Windir%\System32 folder.

I have omitted a few of the notes included with the instruction.

**To reinstall:**

1. Click Start, click Run, type Appwiz.cpl, and then click OK.
2. In the Add/Remove Programs window, click Add/Remove Windows Components.
3. In the Components box of the Windows Components Wizard, click to select the Internet 4. Information Services (IIS) check box.
4. In the Windows Components Wizard, click Next.
5. When the Windows Components Wizard completes the installation, click Finish.

Comment: Is IIS 5.1 what's included with XP?  I thought it was IIS6.

Comment: Based on the link - IIS 5.0 (Microsoft Windows 2000), IIS 5.1 (Microsoft Windows XP Professional), and IIS 6.0 (Microsoft Windows Server 2003)