# Windows XP IIS 5.1 MetaBase corrupted somehow, reinstalling doesn't help

Tags: corruption, iis, metabase

Somehow my MetaBase.bin is corrupted on my Windows XP machine. I've attempted to uninstall and reinstall IIS numerous times. I did see the [Reinstalling IIS on WinXP machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/98421/reinstalling-iis-on-winxp-machine/98520#98520) post here which I made sure to follow exactly however after uninstalling IIS the Inetserv folder does not get completely removed it is left with.

MetaBase.bin aqadmin.dll aqueue.dll seos.dll

Anytime I delete those files they immediately reappear.

When I attempt to reinstall IIS I am presented with:

iis6.log

```
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:ProcessSection.[register_iis_core_dcom].Start.
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=74...
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=76...
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=86...
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:Calling ProcessSection:register_iis_core_dcom:End.return=1
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=47...
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:ProcessEntry_If:check if [51=6]
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=5...
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:Calling ProcessSection:register_iis_core_fillmetabase:Start.
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:ProcessSection.[register_iis_core_fillmetabase].Start.
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=106...
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:SetAdminACL:(/)Start.
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:SetAdminACL:Write the new security descriptor to the Metabase:Start.
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:SetAdminACL:  At this point we have already been able to write basic entries to the metabase, so...
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:SetAdminACL:  If this has a problem then there is a problem with setting up encryption for the metabase (Crypto).
[3/10/2010 19:3:2] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:WriteSDtoMetaBase:Start.
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MyMessageBox: Title:IIS Setup Error, Msg:CoGetClassObject

0x80080005=Server execution failed

[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:WriteSDtoMetaBase:End.  Return=0x80080005
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:SetAdminACL:Write the new security descriptor to the Metabase:End.
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:SetAdminACL(/):End.
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MyMessageBox: Title:IIS Setup Error, Msg:Do you want to retry?
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=86...
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=2...
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:------------------
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:CallProcedureInDll(C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\iislog.dll): DllRegisterServer
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:iOleInitialize: Succeeded: 0.  MakeSure to call OleUninitialize.
[3/10/2010 19:3:32] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:CallProcedureInDll: Calling 'DllRegisterServer'.Start
[3/10/2010 19:4:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MyMessageBox: Title:IIS Setup Error, Msg:Error calling procedure 'DllRegisterServer()' in file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\iislog.dll'.


0x8000ffff=Catastrophic failure

[3/10/2010 19:4:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:!FAIL! 
[3/10/2010 19:4:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:CallProcedureInDll: Calling 'DllRegisterServer'.End.FAILED. Err=8000ffff.
[3/10/2010 19:4:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:------------------
[3/10/2010 19:4:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MyMessageBox: Title:IIS Setup Error, Msg:Do you want to retry?
[3/10/2010 19:4:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=86...
[3/10/2010 19:4:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=84...
[3/10/2010 19:4:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MigrateInfSectionToMD:(CORE_REG_IIS3_UPGRADE)Start.
[3/10/2010 19:4:33] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MyMessageBox: Title:IIS Setup Error, Msg:CoGetClassObject

0x80080005=Server execution failed

[3/10/2010 19:4:33] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MigrateInfSectionToMD(CORE_REG_IIS3_UPGRADE):End.
[3/10/2010 19:4:33] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:...ProcessEntry:100=84...
[3/10/2010 19:4:33] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MigrateInfSectionToMD:(CORE_REG)Start.
[3/10/2010 19:5:3] OC_COMPLETE_INSTALLATION:iis_core:MyMessageBox: Title:IIS Setup Error, Msg:CoGetClassObject

0x80080005=Server execution failed
```

And in the event viewer

Event ID: 7023
The IIS Admin service terminated with the following error: 
The data is invalid.

Event ID: 10010
The server {A9E69610-B80D-11D0-B9B9-00A0C922E750} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem occurred when trying to write the Cryptographic information in the Metabase i.e. iis_core:WriteSDtoMetaBase:Start. I suggest you uninstall IIS. Rename the MachineKeys i.e. machinekeys those are starting with c23 and 7a4. Then try reinstalling IIS.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing anything (I saw similar instructions to this else where tried renaming the entire Crypto folder in all users) it recreated folders but never created anything in the machine keys folder. I tried it again but this time uninstalling IIS and deleting only the machine keys folder and then rebooting and reinstalling again.

Comment: install logs are exactly the same except for date stamps, at this point I don't even have a machine keys folder. Is there some proper way to fix the machine keys first?

Comment: The MachineKeys folder is in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys. You don't have to rename the Crypto folder. Just rename the files as mentioned earlier and that should be good.

Answer (score 0):

System restore actually worked to resolve this... surprisingly.